# Jquery function concatenation. add/remove class to next li only

Tags: jquery, html

Anyone feeling kind enough to help me concatenate this function? ul structure has to remain as is.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80"></a></li>
<li class="hidehot"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/K1SkRxC.png" id="hot"></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/80/80"></a></li>
<li class="hidehot"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/K1SkRxC.png" id="hot"></li>
</ul>

li {
    list-style: none;
}
img#hot {
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.hidehot {
display: none;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   $("li").removeClass("hidehot");   
}); 
/*
    $('img').click(function() {
    $('li').next??.addClass('hidehot');

    ??
*/
```

Jquery removes the hide class on the even numbered li's (.hot) on load, so all are visible.

The odd li/a/img needs to acts as a trigger for adding the 'hide' class for the next even numbered li only.

Then I need any one of several triggers to remove the class again, making it visible.

Hope that makes sense. 
Any help greatly appreciated!!

Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ChilledMonkeyBrain/sLv8gvy9/7/

Comment: Ids should be unique - 'hot' should be class.

Comment: http://www.fillmurray.com/ seems to be down so the fiddle is as confusing as the question. Can you update it?

Comment: Weird.  It was displaying fine for me. Yep, will update it now. Thanks will

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, Will. Changed the fiddle. There a new link.

Comment: Was my question really that bad? God, I suck. Basically, clicking the big image makes the 'hot image' disappear. (Not all of them, just the one that looks like its nested in). Clicking the same image again restores it. (the 'restore ' anchor also restores it). Is that any better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed a little bit of help with your jQuery selector.

```
$("li").removeClass("hidehot");  
$('img').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').next().addClass('hidehot');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLv8gvy9/9/

Do you understand how this works?

Comment: Reading it now, yes I understand. I think i was trying to use .closest or .next, didn't realise I needed both. I still need to figure out the restore, but that should should be fairly easy now I have this function. Thanks for your help.